# Finding the areas of overlap between 514 rasters

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have 514 rasters; each for one species. Each raster file has an attribute table containing only one row that has value, count and name of the species. How can I find the areas of overlap between the 514 rasters without converting to polygons or vector files?

[image]

Comment: Do all the rasters have the same extent, i.e. number of rows and columns are the same, cell size is the same and where your species is not present is it a nodata cell?

Comment: @Hornbydd The number of rows and columns differs for each raster, but the cell sizes are the same. There is no nodata cell because the raster files are converted from the original shapefiles of the species.

Comment: It was useful to upload the image. You do have nodata, what do you think the pixels are where there is no black pixel, the obvious example is the creek above the place called surrey?  The bigger problem is that from what you say the _extents_ of the rasters are all different. Think of the extent as the bounding box around your data. What might be a pixel of a species in one extent is nodata in another and nodata+ something = nodata.  You need to convert your nodata pixels to zero before you continue, explore the con() tool. There are many examples on the internet in how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new field with a default value as 1 and then use the Raster Calculator using this new field and then extract all the pixels with a value greater than 1...